# UserBased Access to function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

How can I implement a function that only the user named Admin can access?
**Its important to do this without roles!**

Like:
[Autohrize] => logged in users 

But i want:
if username is like admin => you can access the page

Thank you

Comment: [Autohrize(User="admin")] how about this ?

Comment: [Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]. this can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get you correct, you want to authorize user with user name. You can do that with custom authorize attribute.

```
public class UserNameAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        dynamic user = HttpContext.Current.Session["user"];
        return user.name == "Admin";
    }
}
```

More detail can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The different options are listed in this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.98).aspx) article.  The option you want is the decorator "[Authorize(Users = "admin")]" for the SpecificUsersOnly method.

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
     ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

     return View();
   }

   public ActionResult About()
   {
       return View();
   }

   [Authorize]
   public ActionResult AuthenticatedUsers()
   {
       return View();
   }

   [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super User")]
   public ActionResult AdministratorsOnly()
   {
       return View();
   }

   [Authorize(Users = "admin")]
   public ActionResult SpecificUserOnly()
   {
       return View();
   }
 }
```